# MediaWiki: Enable text compression

Tags: performance, mediawiki, compression, gzip, text

From a Google Pagespeed Insights test it seems my MediaWiki website lacks **text-compression**;
reading about this, it seems I lack this because I don't have Gzip compression on.
I Ran [this gzip test](https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/) and it seems indeed my website lacks Gzip compression.

Interpreting [this article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseGzip), I tried to add Gzip by adding to following input to the end of `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgUseGzip = true;
```

Yet Gzip wasn't added.

I find no other manual literature about this
How to allow Gzip for a MediaWiki website?

Comment: `$wgUseGzip` is specific to using the file cache (as the documentation page tells yout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate compression using .htaccess file if your server supports it.

Just create a ".htaccess" file on your http root with this contents and run the test again:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Seems this also needs to be added: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_enable_gzip_compression_for_your_pages/